# Checking all Qt signal/slot connection

Tags: qt, qt4, signals-slots

we done a lot of namespace refactoring. One big problems for us is now, that we only can check at runtime,  if we have wrong signal/slot connections.

Is there a external tool, code analyser or a method, which we can check all signal/slot connection at once?

We think about froglogic squish, but we are not quite sure, if squish can help us in this detailed testing.

Thanks in advance,
Lars

Answer (score 1):

There is a thing, that might be useful for you: **Conan 1.0.0:**. It works only on qt 4.6 and 4.7.
See [topic @qtCentre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35352-Conan-1.0.0-signal-slot-connection-debugging-made-easy)

Also I can recommend you **Visual Assist X** addIn tool for MSVStudio 200x and 2010 from http://www.wholetomato.com/, which has MANY solutions for refactoring. E.g.: renaming tool:

---

[image]

---

If you set checkbox "Comments and Strings" it will also rename this symbol everywhere in your code, in whole solution. So if you had correct connections and just refactoring namespaces and classes, this tool can help you. I hope so.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but conan only does not what we need. IT only shows the connection of currently instanced widgets/class. Also have problems with model dialogues.

Answer (score 0):

Conan (sourceforge.net/projects/conanforqt/) will not help you with your problem as it can only examine and monitor existing connections at run-time.

As far as I know there is no tool that can check during compile time if all connection definitions are valid. Note that this is probably not even feasible, as connections can be dynamically constructed from local variables, input arguments, etc.

The only option I see is to find all places where connections are made. For each connection, check for any obvious problems: const correct, argument types not names, etc. Place a breakpoint and start debugging. Any incorrect connection will be logged to the console output / std:err by Qt.

Good luck

p.s.: you mentioned

> Also have problems with model dialogues

Does this apply to Conan? If so can you provide me with details so I can update Conan?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but i have problem with _modal_ dialogues. If a modal dialogue is on focus, i can't do anything in the conan widget.